# How to map aggregate results to java pojo

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    group("$meta_data.user_data.first_name", "$meta_data.user_data.last_name", "$meta_data.user_data.profile_pic", "$user_id")
);
AggregationResults<UsersMongoResult> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "chatuser_log", UsersMongoResult.class);

public class UsersMongoResult {
        private String first_name;
        private String last_name;
        private String profile_pic;
        private String user_id;
    }
```

when I mapped the results to pojo class only user_id mapped. How do I map other fields to particular fileds. I was unable to find a solution in internet also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation to get the desired result.

Spring default is to use part of the field name as key name. For example `user_data.first_name` will be key name for `meta_data.user_data.first_name` and is the reason why the mapping fails.

Update to use `MongoTemplate` `Fields` `group` variant to explicitly map the field key names as java class fields name for spring to map them correctly.

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            group(Fields.fields().and("first_name", "meta_data.user_data.first_name").and("last_name","meta_data.user_data.last_name").and("profile_pic", "meta_data.user_data.profile_pic").and("user_id", "user_id"))
    );
```

Comment: Sorry, the keys were already mapped in `$group` stage before I tried to override them in `$project`. So changed now to use similar code in grouping stage. Can you try now ?